# SHA2 checksum for Sierra's InstallESD.dmg?

Tags: install, security, macos

Before making a bootable drive for Sierra's installer i want to make sure that the download was successful.

Run in Terminal: `shasum -a 256 "/Applications/Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg"`

Wait some minutes for the result to show up.

Mine is: `78a2701bb63a0dcb30862314d1a4598522cfe6a2dd2b096a4e30f256909a4446`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comprehensive list of **sha1** checksums of the InstallESD.dmg (or similar files) in various OS X/macOS installer apps is available here: [Mac OSX Installers SHA1 Checksums](https://github.com/notpeter/apple-installer-checksums#mac-osx-installers-sha1-checksums).

The **sha2** checksum of the InstallESD.dmg of macOS Sierra 10.12.0 is indeed: 78a2701bb63a0dcb30862314d1a4598522cfe6a2dd2b096a4e30f256909a4446

Answer (score 1):

> Mine is:
>   `78a2701bb63a0dcb30862314d1a4598522cfe6a2dd2b096a4e30f256909a4446`

Agreed :

```
78a2701bb63a0dcb30862314d1a4598522cfe6a2dd2b096a4e30f256909a4446
```